# How to programmatically implement @AutoConfigureStubRunner

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

In my project, I have more than 20 stubs to deploy. 

If I use @AutoConfigureStubRunner, the test startup speed will be affected.

I have tried using "StubRunnerRule", but I don't know how to inject "idsToServiceIds". 

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `idsToServiceIds` you need to use Spring Cloud Ribbon. Otherwise, it won't work properly. What is the slowest for you exactly? 20 stubs sounds like an antipattern but I understand that you know what you're doing. Downloading of stubs is done synchronously ATM. You can file an issue so that we add an option to fetch it in parallel.

Comment: I have not tested using 20 stubs.In fact, the project does not have so many stubs. I'm thinking too much. 
thank you for your reminder, now I use `serviename.ribbon.listOfServers`. It solved my problem.